# Magento- Memcache error

Tags: magento, memcached

I’m having some issues with memcached on my server. It appears to be all installed and running correctly (telnet localhost 11211 – stats shows all ok). However when I enable it in Magento it seems to use an old cache that contains an error on the payment page. If I disable memcached in Magento (by removing the xml in local.xml) then the checkout works correctly again.
I’ve tried flush_all and I’ve tried leaving memcached off for a few days but the error keeps coming back.

I think the bad cache is appearing because the first time I enabled memcached there was an error on my site. So I corrected the error and re enabled memcached…

Can I completely clear memcached so it doesn’t use old cache? Is my configuration incorrect?

This is the code I am using in local.xml

```
<cache>
    <prefix>alphanumeric</prefix>
    <backend>memcached</backend><!-- apc / memcached / empty=file -->
    <memcached><!-- memcached cache backend related config -->
        <servers><!-- any number of server nodes can be included -->
            <server>
                <host><![CDATA[127.0.0.1]]></host>
                <port><![CDATA[11211]]></port>
                <persistent><![CDATA[1]]></persistent>
            </server>
        </servers>
    <compression><![CDATA[0]]></compression>
    <cache_dir><![CDATA[]]></cache_dir>
    <hashed_directory_level><![CDATA[]]></hashed_directory_level>
    <hashed_directory_umask><![CDATA[]]></hashed_directory_umask>
    <file_name_prefix><![CDATA[]]></file_name_prefix>
  </memcached>
</cache>
```

Thanks

Comment: Telnetting in and issuing `flush_all` should invalidate the cache. Have you cleared the Magento cache via System > Cache Management?

Comment: Well I was wondering if I needed to flush the magento cache also. Are the two related?

Comment: Yes, but when you telnet & select flush_all that should be authoritative and equal to clicking the Flush Cache Storage button.

Comment: Magento uses 2 levels cache. Maybe it cleaned up slow backend (which I suppose is file in your case) but didn't clean fast backend (memcache) when you invalidated caches from magento admin. Try invalidate caches  from admin and use @Ben suggestion to manually clean up memcached cache via telnet.

Comment: @sulman, did you enable the "compile" function? If that so, first stop the memcache, clear var/cache directory via ssh, then disable the "compile" option. After that, you can start memcache again. Sometimes, I can face of same issue in my linux server.

Comment: @OğuzÇelikdemir no I don't have compilation enabled. I'm hoping the issue is because I didn't clear the cache directory out however I'm currently reluctant to test this due to the the fact that it may cause problems with the checkout during the busiest time of year! I will test once business dies down a little and report back. Thanks all.

Comment: @sulman I just checked my configuration which isn't available <prefix> tag, fyi.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue sounds like a stale cache due to the lack of 2 level caching in your config.

The easiest way to permanently clear Memcache is to simply restart the daemon. It is a non-persistent storage mechanism, so its contents are lost on instance reboot.

I would strongly suggest reading this http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-kb/what-is-memcache-actually-caching-in-magento/